# How to run process in background using gcloud ssh

Tags: ssh

I have two gcp linux VMs, with that I am doing ssh from one instance to another and running process using below command, that works fine when command #1 is executed but when I  use option to run process in background command #2, the command shows no results.

```
gcloud compute ssh -zone {Zone-Name} {vm1} -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log' ==== This works fine
gcloud compute ssh -zone {Zone-Name} {vm2} -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log &' === This does not gets executed.
```

Need way to start process in background, event I log out of this ssh seesion from VM2

Comment: cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/51681286/4023950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no idea of gcp linux, I suppose, the second example doesn't work because "&" is used by the shell to run commands in background. But ssh doesn't start any shell when you specify a command, it just runs the command, then exits.

So, if my assumption is right, you need to login to the remote system and execute commands using expect-like chat-language or try sending the whole command to background on your local system. Something like that:

```
nohup gcloud compute ssh -zone {Zone-Name} {vm2} -- 'cd /app/bin && ./clearcache && nohup ./startWeblogicAdmin >> admin.log' &
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem